# ¿Cómo veo el tiempo de ejecución de un script y lo guardo en un fichero?

Tags: linux, bash

Necesito ejecutar el comando `time` para medir el tiempo de ejecución de un script que armé y luego redirigir la salida a otro archivo.

El error que me está dando es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> orden no encontrada

Cuando hago la redirección, se crea el archivo si previamente no existía pero totalmente en blanco

Comment: fíjate que `time 01_monopr.sh` no funciona porque el comando `01_monopr.sh` en sí tampoco lo haría. De ahí que explique en mi respuesta lo de usar `bash` para ejecutarlo, o bien darle permisos de ejecución con `chmod +x script.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Para contar cuánto tarda un script en ejecutarse debes decir:

```
time script.sh
```

---

Esto presupone que el fichero tiene permisos de ejecución (`chmod +x script.sh`). Si no es así, puedes decir:

```
time bash script.sh
```

Con lo que Bash se encargará de ejecutarlo.

---

Para redirigir el contenido a otro fichero, usa algo así como:

```
{ time <comando> 2> comando.stderr ; } 2> time.log
```

Con lo que "comando.stderr" tendrá el resultado de stderr de la ejecución, mientras que "time.log" tendrá el resultado de la ejecución de `time`.

Comment: No me funcionó. Ejecuté { time 01_monopr.sh 2> error.txt ; } > test.txt con el mismo resultado. Test.txt aparece vacío.

Comment: Si con { time 01_monopr.sh 2> error.txt ; } > test.txt tienes el texto vacio, es porque, 1) el script monopr.sh no lanza ningún resultado, o 2) No lanza ningun resultado por algún error registrado en error.txt. Intenta correr el comando time 01_monopr.sh sin redigir, y tambien abre el contenido de "error.txt", para ver si hay pistas. De ahi en fuera, la respuesta de fedorqui es la que va a tu caso. Todo lo demás será cuestión de tu script o de algún typo.

Comment: Ejecutando { time ./01_monopr.sh 2> error.txt ; } > test.txt me graba el resultado de la ejecución en test.txt

Comment: @LuisUrán claro, `> test.txt` lo que hace es redirigir la salida normal al fichero test.txt.